# Is there any pane for seeing my comments?

Tags: support, comments, profile-page

I wonder if theres any way (like we have pages for answers, questions, etc.) similar to what we could have for our comments too as it's very difficult to check sometimes what question/answer I'd put a comment on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to see all of your comments. They are listed in your profile:

1. Go to your user profile page.
2. Click the "Activity" tab.
3. Click the "All actions" tab.
4. Click the "Comments" tab.

The direct link is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=comments

(Note that deleted comments are not shown here.)

Comment: If one does want to see their deleted comments, [this userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Comment-History-Checker) can help